# How to make a drop chance of a item on button click

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a clicker type game and one section has like a mine. I want the mine when your Mininglv < 10 to have a 50% chance when you click it top drop 1 bronze. I'm new to HTML and not sure how `math.random works`. I want to maybe later add a way to upgrade the chance so maybe I should define the first drop chance as BronzeDropChance.

I've tried this:

```
var Minechance = Math.random();  

function Miningaction(){
    if (MiningCexp < NextMaxMiningExp && Mininglv < 10){
        MiningCexp = MiningCexp + 1;
        if(Minechance < 0.5)
            Bronze = Bronze + 1
        document.getElementById("Bronze").innerHTML = Bronze;
        document.getElementById("MiningCexp").innerHTML = MiningCexp;
        }else{
```

This is the rest of my code for mining:

```
var Bronze = 0;
var Silver = 0;
var Gold = 0;
var Diamond = 0;

var Mining = 1;
var Mininglv = 1;
var MiningCexp = 0;
var MiningMexp = 100;
var NextMaxMiningExp =  MiningMexp;
var Minechance = Math.random();

function Miningaction(){
    if (MiningCexp < NextMaxMiningExp && Mininglv < 10){
        MiningCexp = MiningCexp + 1;
        if(Minechance < 0.5)
            Bronze = Bronze + 1
        document.getElementById("Bronze").innerHTML = Bronze;
        document.getElementById("MiningCexp").innerHTML = MiningCexp;
        }else{
        Mininglv = Mininglv + 1
        MiningCexp = 0
        Mining = Mining + 1
        NextMaxMiningExp = NextMaxMiningExp * 1.5;
        document.getElementById('MiningMexp').innerHTML = 
NextMaxMiningExp;
        document.getElementById('Mininglv').innerHTML = Mininglv;
        document.getElementById('MiningCexp').innerHTML = MiningCexp;
        document.getElementById('Mining').innerHTML = Mining;
    }
}
```

HTML markup for reference on how I have it formatted: (I don't have a button for every skill yet just using one button to test if the skills works)

```
Mining: Lv <span id="Mininglv">1</span> <span id="MiningCexp">0</span> / 
<span id="MiningMexp">100</span>
                    <br />
                    Fishing: Lv <span id="Fishinglv">1</span> <span 
id="FishingCexp">0</span> / <span id="FishingMexp">100</span>
                    <br />
                    <button onclick="Miningaction()">Click Me!</button>
                    <br />
                </div>
```

I expect after clicking the button for exp to always go up by 1 and also while mining lv below 10 for there to be a 50% chance drop of bronze so it would get added to the inventory:

[image]

But the actual output it doesn't drop any bronze at all no matter how much I click it. I'm sure I have it formatted wrong.

Comment: Try doing `if(Math.random() < 0.5)` or ressetting `MineChance`  in your statements, otherwise it will remain as the same constant value that it is initialized to on startup

Comment: that worked thanks. if you post that as a answer i can say answered

Comment: So i can set MineBronzeChance to 0.5 at the start then later i can have that upgraded. same if i add more materials

Comment: Yep, and that will make it easier down the line if you go to review your code and aren't sure what your constants are meant to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MineChance` is initially set to `Math.Random()`, which will give you a value between 0 and 1, but it will stay as that value throughout the program. If you change the if statement to `if(Math.random() < 0.5)` or resetting `MineChance` to a new `Math.random()` in your statements (if you want it as a variable), otherwise it will remain as the same constant value that it is initialized to on startup.